# How does 'jealousy' mean 'suspicion'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage

> In practically every town of any size an intelligent workman who wanted to
>   improve and educate himself would find by the forties a Mechanics’ Institution, or
>   some similar society. In England, in 1850, it was estimated that there were seven
>   hundred of these societies with 107,000 members. The libraries connected with
>   them contained over 690,000 books. But though the figures sound impressive, these
>   institutions caused much searching of heart. They had failed to fulfil the
>   expectations of their founders. Their rate of mortality was high, though their birthrate
>   was also high, and even in those that were comfortably established the
>   membership was apt to fluctuate with alarming rapidity. To understand their
>   position, it is necessary to glance back at their origins.
>
> These institutions were started by Brougham and Birkbeck in the twenties at a time
>   when, as a writer described it, “there still prevailed in many quarters a strong
>   **jealousy** of any political discussion by the people, and still more of any society
>   which proposed to assemble periodically several hundreds of the labouring
>   classes”. Hence their founders, in their desire to conciliate opposition, banned
>   political or religious discussion or books, and forbade newspapers.

How do you determine the closest meaning to **jealousy**? Is it   (a) Envy    (b) Suspicion   (c) Disapproval
 (d) Fear   (e) Resentment ?

I see that [ODO's definition 1.1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jealous#jealous__3) states 'a resentful suspicion', but the context is amorous and romantic, so I thought (b) doesn't fit . Yet (b)'s the answer.

I also tried Definition 1(.0), which states 'envious resentment'. This excessively confuses me, because this suggets either (a) or (e)?

Comment: Of the five options provided, when you plug each in, which renders the sentence most sensible and appropriate in context?

Comment: @DanBron Thanks, but upon substitution, they all look right?

Comment: If you lived in NYC, it'd be so much easier to just talk through these things than type them up. But, c'est le vie. Maybe I can clear this up by sharing a revelation I once had: originally, *jealousy* meant the desire to keep *my things* for *just myself*, whereas *envy* meant desiring *your things* for *myself*. That is, I'm *jealous* of *my* wife (don't touch her!) but covet *your* wife (she's so pretty!), so I'm *envious* of you. Similarly, above, the social elites *jealously guarded* the right to political discourse as properly *their domain*, and wanted it kept out of the laity's hands.

Comment: In conjunction with Dan Bron's good explanation, see definition #2 here http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jealousy

Comment: Note that we are asked about the meaning of "jealousy" written in the 1820's. Words change their meaning. I don't know what word would have been used in the 1820's to mean "suspicion", but assuming that I don't know the correct meaning of "jealousy", "suspicion" is the best match with the surrounding text.

Comment: @DanBron Thank you! +1. Would you please explain how your comment proves (b) as the choice, though? And none of (C)-(e) inclusively?

Answer (score 2):

God did not write those test questions; a fallible human being did. The only answer that is dead wrong is (a). All of the others are valid, and which is the best answer depends on how you assess the actions taken by the founders of these organizations to appease those who were having this "strong jealousy": *they banned discussion of politics and religion; they banned books; and they forbade newspapers*. Would such actions have alleviated (b) Suspicion (c) Disapproval (d) Fear or (e) Resentment?

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jealousy  (#2)

Comment: Would you please explain how your answer proves (b) as the choice, though? Or do you opine that (b) to (e) are all equally valid answers?

Comment: The artistocratic class *feared* a labor rebellion.  They *suspected* that political issues would be discussed at labor guild meetings. Banning politics from the meetings might have alleviated that suspicion, but it would not have alleviated the underlying fear.

Comment: Thank you again. But why not (a), (c), or (e)? Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment?

Comment: @LePress I think TRomano covers this already in his answer. You're looking for a normative answer, but none exists. A case could be made for several of the available choices, so it falls to us to select the *best possible* choice, given the context. Which comes down, as many of your recent questions do,  to critical interpretation (which abandons concepts like "proof"). His answer provides a compelling, credible, and solid interpretation which leads us to select *suspicion* as the *best available* choice (because the actions taken *could not change* resentment, disapproval, etc).

Comment: @DanBron Thanks, but how's (b) 'the *best possible* choice, given the context'? I might have misinterpreted `All of the others are valid` in the answer above, but does user TRomano suggest that any one of (b) to (e) can be an answer? Yet the given answer is (b)?

Comment: @LePress, Yes, the point of TRomano's answer and my comment is that there is *no normative answer* to questions of interpretation, so you must choose the *best available* answer (because you may only pick one). Which is *best* has more to do with critical thinking and reasoning than language, but nevertheless TRomano gave a solid rationale for choosing *suspicion* over all the other available answers (remember, you can only pick *one*), and further reinforced his logic in his comment. I tried to elucidate with my comment as well, so now I don't know what else to say to clarify any further.